# Обращение по индексам в Pandas с инверсией (исключить индексы из выборки)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, индексация

Не смог найти в документации: 
Есть список индексов которые мне **НЕ** нужно выводить. 
Как вывести с помощью `.loc` или как-то иначе индексы вне этого списка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один способ:

```
idx = [1,3,5]

In [82]: df.query("index not in @idx")
Out[82]:
   col1  col2
0     1     3
2     3     5
4     5     7
6     7     9
7     8    10
8     9    11
```

Comment: Элегантно. Благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

Есть подозрение, что вы не очень хорошо искали.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'col2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]})
print(df)

   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     5
3     4     6
4     5     7
5     6     8
6     7     9
7     8    10
8     9    11
```

Выводим "срез":

```
print(df.loc[1:5])
   col1  col2
1     2     4
2     3     5
3     4     6
4     5     7
5     6     8
```

Выводим без одного элемента (не самый элегантный способ:

```
print(df.loc[df.index != 1])
   col1  col2
0     1     3
2     3     5
3     4     6
4     5     7
5     6     8
6     7     9
7     8    10
8     9    11
```

Выводим без элементов из списка:

```
print(df.loc[~df.index.isin([1,3,5])])
   col1  col2
0     1     3
2     3     5
4     5     7
6     7     9
7     8    10
8     9    11
```